# How do I swap two (or more) columns in two different data tables? on pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, swap

new here and I am new to programming. 
So.. as the title says I am trying to swap two full columns from two different files (columns has the same name but different data). I started this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('table1.csv', col_name= 'COL1')
df1 = pd.read_csv('table2.csv', col_name = 'COL1')
df1.COL1 = df.COL1
```

But now I am stack.. how do I select whole column and how can I print the new combined table to a new file (i.e table 3)?

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the swapping by copying one column in a temporary one and deleting afterwards like follows

```
df1['temp'] = df1['COL1']
df1['COL1'] = df['COL1']
df['COL1'] = df1['temp']
del df1['temp']
```

and then writing the result via [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to a third CSV

```
df1.to_csv('table3.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you, I acctualy did it with  df1['COL1'] = df['COL1'] but the problem now that it creates a new column with numbers (same with your version)

Comment: Can you add an example and outline how the data looks like at the moment and what is the expected state.

Comment: Left align | COL1| COL2 |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 0|        NAN|     NAN     |
| 1|      12|    14|
| 2|        15|     12|
| 3|          5|      5|
| 4|       64|    0| It's just an example  --> the left side with numbers appeared next to COL 1  ..(I don't know how to show it as a table form here)

Comment: You can do `print(df)` and then attach the output to the original question. It would be useful to see the relevant part of the two DataFrames to be swapped and what you would expect to happen after the swap resp. how the third table should look like.

Comment: 0    luad_tcga_pan_can_atlas_2018  TCGA-05-4244-01  ...     WT       WT
1    luad_tcga_pan_can_atlas_2018  TCGA-05-4249-01  ...     WT       WT
2    luad_tcga_pan_can_atlas_2018  TCGA-05-4250-01  ...     WT       WT
3    luad_tcga_pan_can_atlas_2018  TCGA-05-4382-01  ...     WT       WT
4    luad_tcga_pan_can_atlas_2018  TCGA-05-4384-01  ...     WT       WT
             


[503 rows x 20 columns]
The numbers on the left are meaningless (they happen to be on df1 printing either)